# Trying to make a schedule for 5 people playing double but how?

Tags: combinations

[Wrong solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFoEw.png)

I have tried to make a schedule for player a, b, c, d, e with some criteria:

- Two people are playing on each team.
- Each pair should play against each pair possible (each pair is playing against 3 different pairs).
- There should be equal time between breaks, e.g. if someone takes a break, the player should play 4 matches before the person is taking a break.
- After every 5 rounds, each unique pair should only have played once together, e.g. player a and player b should not play two games together in the first 5 games. (This is not fulfilled in my example since player b and d are already playing together in match 6 and 8).

To explain the last criteria:
[Overview of each unique pair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7dyZ.png). Each of these pairs should only have played 1 time after 5 rounds, 2 times after 10 rounds, 3 times after 15 rounds.

I think it should be possible to make or is this an impossible problem? Have been using the last 5 hours trying to solve this but maybe there is a smart way?

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the problem, but if the first 5 games are fine, then how about using permutation?
After replacing b and c, change the order of games so that breaks for players are fair.

Comment: ab, cd, e. ac, be, d. ae, bd, c. ad, ce, b. bc, de, a.

Comment: @MathDrifter Yes, I have the [all the combinations](https://i.imgur.com/Eofg2fb.png). But arranging the order where  the breaks are even and that a pair is not playing two times in 5 rounds is the problem.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks, that works for the first 5 rounds but it's the last 10 rounds which is difficult.

Comment: @MauriceSchneider So the 2nd & 4th criteria are about a streak of 15 rounds, right? Each combination should be done once in a streak. I saw it is impossible. Not answering because I did brute-force.

Comment: @MathDrifter Yes, I thought 15 since after 15 rounds, each pair has played against all possible combinations. 
Oh, so it is actually impossible? Then I understand why I couldn't find a solution.